# accountExpires attribute value inconistent

Tags: active-directory

When I look at some accountExpire values in AD they show the time as 23:00:00 (using w32tm to translate). If I change the date the time remains at 23:00:00.

However if I then pick another user account and set the date the time value is 00:00:00. If I move the date the time remains at 00:00:00.

Why would the attribute be handled differently on two accounts in the same OU/DC/Domain ?

Comment: Can you reformulate your question please ?

Comment: When setting the Account Expires field in AD Users and Computers to a date (e.g., 25/12/2013), the underlying value is stored as 24:12:2013 00:00:00.

However, there are some accounts that have the underlying value stored as 24:12:2013 23:00:00

I cannot see why the time values would be stored differently for different accounts.

Comment: What is your location ? Are all your servers and users in the same time zone ?

Comment: Hi - yes they are. I made the changes on the same DC. It seems like once it has a time value of 23:00:00 then it retains this when changing the date. Maybe the leaving date was originally set in a different time zone..?